# Mixing Windows authentication and claimsPrincipal in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, windows-authentication, claims, principal

I have a MVC project with windows authentication and i want to use [Claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx). 
I see that claims inherit from IPrincipal. I think that used for authentication reasons, because in every request before code will be executed validate users credentials. 
I this possible? Where have to define claims?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. do you want to issue token based windows authentication?

Comment: Please see [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43978103/3588633) if relevant to your question: